Is Python's `list.clear()` thread-safe?
In Python, suppose one thread is appending/popping items to/from a list/collections.deque/similar built-in container, while another thread occasionally empties the container via its clear() method. Is this interaction thread-safe? Or is it possible for the clear() to interfere with a concurrent append()/pop() operation, leaving the list uncleared or corrupted?
My interpretation of the accepted answer here suggests that the GIL should prevent such interference, at least for lists. Am I correct?
As a related follow-up, if this is not thread-safe, I suppose I should use a queue.Queue instead. But what is the best (i.e., cleanest, safest, fastest) way to clear it from the second thread? See the comments on this answer for concerns about using the (undocumented) queue.Queue().queue.clear() method. Need I really use a loop to get() all the items one by one?

AFAIK, all built-in operations are supposed to be thread-safe, due to the use of the GIL.

Even if the clear method was "thread safe," how could you coordinate the activity of the thread that "occasionally empties the container" while the "one thread is appending/popping items" if you don't use Lock objects to stop the threads from interfering with each other? Even if "clear" can never corrupt Python's idea of what a list should look like in general, that does not mean that your program's idea of what that particular list should contain won't be corrupted. Building a program entirely from thread-safe objects does not guarantee that the program itself is "thread safe."

@SolomonSlow Admittedly, I didn't give a lot of details about my particular use-case. I'm appending to a queue (I'm actually using a deque because of its maxlen feature) on one thread and periodically processing and clearing it on a separate thread. It's true that I will fail to process items added between processing and clearing, but that isn't a problem in my case, and I can't think of any other issues with this approach.

@charlescochran please - I had to change the answer substantially after it was accepted - check it is still valid for you.

@jsbueno Thanks for the update. See my comment below.

update Methods like list.clear are not atomic in the sense that other threads can add elements to the list (or other container) before the method returns to the current code. They are "thread safe" in the sense that they won't ever be in an inconsistent state that will cause an exception - but not "atomic" .
In other words: the list object will never be "broken" with or without the use of a Lock - but whatever will be inside it is not deterministic.
The following snippet inserts data before list.clear() returns both in the same thread, and from other thread:
import threading, time

class A:
    def __init__(self, container, delay=0.2):
        self.container = container
        self.delay = delay
    def __del__(self):
        time.sleep(self.delay)
        self.container.append("thing")

def doit():
    target = []
    def interferer():
        time.sleep(0.1)
        target.append("this tries to be first")
    target.append(A(target, delay=0.3))
    t = threading.Thread(target=interferer)
    t.start()
    target.clear()
    return target

In [37]: doit()
Out[37]: ['this tries to be first', 'thing']



So, if one needs a "thread-safe" and "atomic" sequence - it has to be crafted from collections.abc.MutableSequence and the appropriate locks in the methods that perform mutations.
original answer
As put in the comments: all operations on built-in data structures are thread safe in Python  - what have ensured this up to this day is the GIL (global interpreter lock), which otherwise penalizes multi-threading code in Python.
For Python3.13 onwards, there will be the option of running Python code without the GIL, but it is a language guarantee that such operations on built-in data structures will remain thread-safe, by the use of finer grained locking - check the Container Thread Safety session on PEP 703 (as it not only explains the mechanism forward, as re-asserts the current status quo of these modifications being effectively atomic thead safe, though not "atomic")
However, depending on the code you have, you may wish to express the list modification with another operation instead os a method calling - since some methods can't be atomic. The linked session on PEP 703 above gives the example of list.extend, which, if used with a generator object simply can't be atomic. So to lessen the chances of someone changing your code in the future, clearing the list can be expressed with mylist[:] = () - I have the feeling one would think twice before replacing this with a method call which could lead to undesired race conditions.

Doesn't that PEP actually say that the operations are not guaranteed to be atomic? Quote: "The GIL does not necessarily ensure that operations are atomic or remain correct when multiple operations occur concurrently. For example, list.extend(iterable) may not appear atomic if the iterable has an iterator implemented in Python (or releases the GIL internally)." Similarly, clear() could remove an element which has no other references, so that its __del__ is called and that could likewise be "implemented in Python (or releases the GIL internally)."

Indeed - clearing and otherwise emptying the list are not "atomic" - the language guarrantee is that the list object won't be broken - and that they are thread-safe - but synchronous triggered events in the same thread can change it.

@jsbueno To extend your answer, if you run the same test with the list initialized as target = ['old1', 'old2'] instead of target = [], you get the same result (['this tries to be first', 'thing']), indicating that the target.clear() successfully removed the old items. Of course, you have manually created a race condition here regarding what order the other two elements are inserted (and whether the first one gets cleared), but I feel like the clearing semantics are quite deterministic here, so I think it is safe to use. That being said, I will probably opt for a lock for clarity.

Yes - the existing elements on the list at the point .clear() is called are always removed: at some point before the function returns the list length is set to 0 - on the aftermath of that, things might happen, and it gets complicated though. A simple "locking sequence" I scratched using collections.abc.MutableMapping simply dropped the element inserted from a concurrent thread during the "clear" call :-(  - this sort of thing have to be done carefully.

@jsbueno By dropped, you mean the element's constructor was never called at all (as opposed to simply being deleted via the clear right after being created and inserted)? Yes, this does sound tricky, which explains why a lot of the SO discussion around this subject seems rather murky.

I could figure it out  -  it turns out that simply adding the lock to the mandatory methods modiied methods listed in the  collections.abc.MutableSequence documentation isn´t enough: that class' clear implementation will make one call to __delitem__ for each element. Implementing def clear(self): with self.lock: super().clear() solved that for elements comming from other threads.

But for the edge case of an element being inserted in a  __del__ side effect - which takes place in the same thread .clear() is called, that isn't enough - and another internal state besides a  self.lock = threading.RLock() is needed if that is to be covered, for example.
